# Base64 Encode giving me different value for c# and java

Tags: java, c#, encoding, base64, tobase64string

I have been trying to get same encoding in my C# code which I am getting from my Java code.

In Java this is what I am doing:

```
    JSONObject claimSet = new JSONObject();
    claimSet.put("partnerUrl", "https://test.com/testapply/abc/signup");

    String claimSetJson = claimSet.toString();
    byte[] claimSetJsonBytes = claimSetJson.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    
    String claimSetBase64 = 
    Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(claimSetJsonBytes);
```

and the calimSetBase64 value is `eyJwYXJ0bmVyVXJsIjoiaHR0cHM6XC9cL3Rlc3QuY29tXC90ZXN0YXBwbHlcL2FiY1wvc2lnbnVwIn0=`

And the equivalent code I have written in c# is:

```
        var claimSets = new Dictionary<string, object>()
            {
                { "partnerUrl", "https://test.com/testapply/abc/signup" },
            };
        string claimSetsJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(claimSets);
        byte[] claimSetsjsonBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(claimSetsJson);
        var claimSetsBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(claimSetsjsonBytes);
```

and now claimSetsBase64 values is `eyJwYXJ0bmVyVXJsIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly90ZXN0LmNvbS90ZXN0YXBwbHkvYWJjL3NpZ251cCJ9`

now if I decode though both of the encoded strings giving me exactly same value, I am expecting the encoded string also should be same, what I am missing here? I have seen similar question asked in [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518321/base64-difference-between-c-sharp-and-java) but according to the accepted answer I am already using UTF8 on both Java and c#.

Comment: Have you compared the strings and the bytes? What are the differences?

Comment: The base64 value from Java should have a trailing `=` on it and all the slashes in the JSON are escaped with backslashes. You should not be using `claimSet.toString()`.

Comment: the JSONObject is coming from this net.minidev.json package @DavidConrad

Comment: yes you are right the end is with =, i copied the text wrong, i updated my question @DavidConrad

Comment: The C# JSON string needs to have escaped forward-slashes.

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: @Reilas Why would you escape forward slashes?

Comment: JSONObject escapes every "/" with "\/" which is *allowed* but not required. C# is NOT doing that. Both are valid. Do you *need* or care about the particular JSON escape mechanism used? It shouldn't really matter...

Comment: because I am trying to construct a jwt token with this encoded string, this going to be the payload part and it should be exactly same encoding as i get in java code

Comment: what matter to me is that I want exact same encoding string, if I can do that without adding back slashes that also would work for me, but it seems like if I want exact same encoded string i need same jsonString,

Comment: @aquinas JSONObject has a toJSONString() method which should be called, not toString().

Comment: I used toJSONString() now and its giving me same encoded string, I am happy with the encoded string what I am getting in java, all I want is get the same encoded string when I give the same claimset

Comment: I would switch to a library like Jackson or GSON that wouldn't escape the slashes, but I suppose you could replace every `/` with `\/` in your C# code.

Comment: Sorry, I just tried minidev myself and, yes, toJSONString() produces the same results. I had wrongly assumed that toString() was just returning something for debugging purposes, and toJSONString() was the proper way to generate JSON with it. I'll withdraw my answer.

Comment: You could also just filter out the backslashes in Java. `String claimSetJson = claimSet.toString().replace("\\/", "/");`

Comment: okay thanks I changed in c# means I replaced / with \/, as I dont have access on original java code, thanks everyone,

Comment: @DavidConrad, because the JSONObject in Java is escaping it.

Answer (score 0):

If you decode your Base64 strings, you will see different original strings.

In Java code you try to encode string: `{"partnerUrl":"https:\/\/test.com\/testapply\/abc\/signup"}`.

In C#: `{"partnerUrl":"https://test.com/testapply/abc/signup"}`

So, string from Java code contains backslash `\` as escape character.

Comment: how can I add blackslash on my c# code because I cant make any changes in Java part, i can adjust only c# code

Comment: @FazlaElahiMdJubayer You do not want to add backslash to your C# code. That is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on the comments from the main question.

As mentioned by *Oleg Spiridonov*, if you decode the data you'll find that the Java implementation is escaping the [solidus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slash_(punctuation)) character.

```json
{"partnerUrl":"https:\/\/test.com\/testapply\/abc\/signup"}
```

```json
{"partnerUrl":"https://test.com/testapply/abc/signup"}
```

There is nothing in the RFC for JSON that mentions escaping the solidus specifically; only the quotation mark, the reverse solidus, and control characters U+0000 through U+001f.
[RFC 8259: The JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) Data Interchange Format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259).

If you look at the source for *JSONObject*, specifically the *[JSONStringify#string](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/f2f7880a40aed1c8d9c27db49226e47396556aac/libcore/json/src/main/java/org/json/JSONStringer.java#302)* method, you'll find they escape all of these mentioned values, including the solidus, on [line 316](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/f2f7880a40aed1c8d9c27db49226e47396556aac/libcore/json/src/main/java/org/json/JSONStringer.java#316).

Additionally, there is an Errata in regard to the solidus, in terms of it's representation within a *string*.
[RFC Errata Report](https://www.rfc-editor.org/errata/eid5318).

Finally, if you look at the [examples](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259#section-13) within RFC 8259, you'll find they are not escaping the solidus.

It is my conclusion that, the solidus being escaped is part of an errata, thus was implemented by the *JSONObject* class, unknowningly.

My suggestion is to implement a method similar to the *JSONStringify#string* method in C#.

This will reduce the overhead required when, if, the *JSONObject* in Java is changed to not escape the solidus.